# how to get current year date and the year count by passing a date in Laravel Carbon?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I'm using Carbon, I expect two functions in my application and I hope those can be done using any Carbon methods. I tried to find it on the internet and could not find an exact answer to my question. So I'm posting it here with the hope someone might help me. Thank you.

what are the functions I expect is:

for example, an event that happened on 2014-05-15

using above date I need to find the event date from current year and how many years for the event now as below,

event from the current year - 2021-05-15
years for the event - 7 years

is there a possible way to do these using any Carbon inbuilt functions?

(I expect this function to a big process in my code and here it's a simple example what should happen)

Comment: Sorry, it isn't very clear what you're after. Are you just trying to find the difference in years between a specific date and now?

Comment: yea the difference will show the year count and also I need the date from this year. thank you

Comment: thanks for the reply @JohnLobo, I think I've provide the input and the output :/

Comment: Everything you need should be in the [documentation](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Carbon::diffInYears

```
$date = Carbon::parse('2021-05-15');
$diffYears = Carbon::now()->diffInYears($date);
```

Refer Carbon doc for more diff methods https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference

Comment: thanks for your reply, is there a possible way to display a past date in the current year, example if we pass 1996-03-21 should display 2021-03-21

Comment: @NasmaNajeeb `$date->setYear(now()->year)`